# How can we delete an object (having an integer identifier)?

Tags: ruby

I would like to delete an object, I can not. Here is an example:

```
irb(main):001:0> str = "hello"
"hello"
irb(main):003:0> str.object_id
2164703880
irb(main):004:0> str = nil
nil
irb(main):005:0> str.object_id
4
```

As you can see, I can just set the variable of the object to *nil* (and then of course its object id will be 4). And after that, the garbage collector will delete automatically the unused object with the id: 2164703880.

But no, I don't want that. I want to remove this object.

Thanks for any ideas, suggestions.

Comment: . Please explain better, I'm not sure I understand your question...

Comment: What do you mean by "delete" versus "remove"?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: We can use delete, remove, destroy... as you prefer :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot un-define a local variable in Ruby.  You can use remove_class_variable, remove_instance_variable and remove_const, but you can't do this for local variables.

In your code you are actually removing the string object, or at least the garbage collector is removing it. The only thing you keep around is a pointer, named str, that points to nil. But the actual string object will no longer exist.

One way to ensure your variables are un-defined is to wrap them in a Proc. Of course this has the downside of having to create a Proc, and it's much easier to let Ruby perform garbage collection. If you do want to use a proc, it will define it's own binding and you can force local variables, like this:

```
Proc.new{ |;str| str = "hello"; puts str.object_id }.call
  2227691880
  => nil
defined?(str)
  => nil
```

Keep in mind that Ruby is an Object Oriented programing language, so it's easier to deal with variables inside of objects rather than to worry about globally scoped variables. If your variables are defined inside of functions and objects, they remain local to those functions and objects and will cease to exist once the objects are removed.

Comment: If you do the equivalent of `ObjectSpace._id2ref(2227691880)` (the number will vary of course), you still get `"hello"`. Even after calling GC.start , for some reason.

Comment: I tried using ObjectSpace.garbage_collect and then calling the ObjectSpace._id2ref and the object had been recycled. If you call _id2ref first and then garbage_collect in the console, you have to do it twice, since _ still stores a reference.

Comment: P.S: @Andrew Grimm - the same applies for GC.start. If you are calling this in the console keep in mind what _ is keeping a reference to. For example, if you call the proc, and then GC.start and then _id2ref you will see that the object is recycled. If you call the proc, then _id2ref, and then GC.start the object won't be recycled since _id2ref stores the object in _.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, and that's a good thing, because of

```
>> str = "hello"
str = "hello"
=> "hello"
>> str2 = str
str2 = str
=> "hello"
>> str.object_id
str.object_id
=> 2157491040
>> str2.object_id
str2.object_id
=> 2157491040
>> str = nil
str = nil
=> nil
>> str.object_id
str.object_id
=> 4
>> str2.object_id
str2.object_id
=> 2157491040
>>
```

I wouldn't want my `str2` to disappear because somewhere else in the program `str` was "removed".

Comment: Don Roby: Of course, and I understand very well. But suppose (just like me) you want to do so despite this. Actually, it's not really logic that you can create explicitly a new object but not destroy it explicitly.